# Locker Service blocking Custom publish from lightning component to canvas

Tags: lightning-aura-components, canvas, locker-service

When trying publish custom event using Sfdc.canvas.controller.publish system is complaining publish of undefined.

Any help.

Comment: I was able to make publish message by deactivating Locker Service and I also found out that similar to this Live Agent issue(salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140139/…) we would need fix from Salesforce for canvas as well. @doug-chasman

Answer (score 0):

The underlying cause of this issue is usage of expandos in the canvas library. The fix for this is tracked under W-3553004. In /canvas/sdk/js/36.0/controller.js

```
(function(global) {
var module = function() {
function subscribe(event) {
  Sfdc.canvas.parent.subscribe(event)
}
function unsubscribe(event) {
  Sfdc.canvas.parent.unsubscribe(event)
}
function publish(event) {
  Sfdc.canvas.parent.publish(event)
}
function resize(size, target) {
  Sfdc.canvas.parent.resize(size, target)
}
return{subscribe:subscribe, unsubscribe:unsubscribe, publish:publish, resize:resize}
}();
global.Sfdc = global.Sfdc || {};
global.Sfdc.canvas = global.Sfdc.canvas || {};
global.Sfdc.canvas.controller = module
})(this);
```

The controller.js code adds an expando called "Sfdc" on global(aka window). Now global.Sfdc ends up being a SecureObject. In the very next line, it tries to set global.Sfdc.canvas and fails silently with this error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'canvas' of object '[object Object]'"